# What is the technical name for an expression of the form "all good men and true"?

Tags: grammar

...by which I mean an expression wherein one of the adjectives modifying a noun precedes that noun and another follows it.

I know that an adjective that appears after the noun it modifies is a Post-positive adjective but I'm not sure that's the same construction.

Comment: I can't offhand think of any other examples, set forms or not, using a three- (or four- with the 'and') word string of the form Adj + N + Adj (where there is no compound noun as in _necessary letters patent_ or necessary postposing to switch meaning as in _wicked people responsible_ / _well-maintained runway proper_).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Because it changes the natural word order of the sentence, it can be considered a form of **hyperbaton**.

It is usually only seen in a poetic or heightened context: "They, hand in hand, with **wandering steps and slow**/Through Eden took their solitary way."

Comment: Beautiful example, but I'm wondering how 'usual' it is for the man on the Clapham Omnibus to be reading – Milton, isn't it:-)